# Bitrise CLI clone a project

Tags: bitrise

I am trying to setup BITRISE CLI, I am unable to download the project source code using BITRISE CLI. How do i clone my project hosted in git hub using bitrise cli in my local machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bitrise CLI is designed to be use in two different ways:

- Use it in a CI environment where retrieving the code should be part of the process.
- Use it on your local Mac/PC where you already have the code so no need to retrieve it.

If you install the CLI and just `bitrise run` on your Mac/PC then it'll run in the second mode, which expects you already have your code there, so the related steps will be skipped.

In a CI environment, or if you want to force the "CI mode" on your own Mac/PC you should set the `CI` environment variable to `true` before you'd run the bitrise cli. The CLI also has a command line flag option which can be used to activate this mode:

```
$ bitrise --help

NAME: bitrise - Bitrise Automations Workflow Runner

USAGE: bitrise [OPTIONS] COMMAND/PLUGIN [arg...]

VERSION: 1.16.1

GLOBAL OPTIONS:
  --loglevel value, -l value  Log level (options: debug, info, warn, error, fatal, panic). [$LOGLEVEL]
  --debug                     If true it enabled DEBUG mode. If no separate Log Level is specified this will also set the loglevel to debug. [$DEBUG]
  --ci                        If true it indicates that we're used by another tool so don't require any user input! [$CI]
  --pr                        If true bitrise runs in pull request mode.
  --help, -h                  show help
  --version, -v               print the version
...
```

As you can see the `--ci` flag can be used to enable this mode (e.g. `bitrise --ci run ...`), as well as the `CI` environment variable.

When you run the Bitrise CLI is CI mode it'll simply set the `.IsCI` `run_if` condition to `true`, otherwise in non CI mode it's `false`. What this means is, there are certain Steps which leverage this flag, and are marked **by default** to only run in CI mode - see for example the Git Clone step's definition: https://github.com/bitrise-io/steps-git-clone/blob/13fc7d29662bc68aaead618a72d499fb0f031d6c/step.yml#L18

You can of course overwrite this `run_if` in your own `bitrise.yml`, it's just the **default** config.

So another way to force a step to run in any environment is you marking it in your `bitrise.yml` with `run_if: true`.

Related links:

- Docs: Enable/Disable a step (optionally, based on a condition): https://devcenter.bitrise.io/tips-and-tricks/disable-a-step-by-condition/#run-a-step-only-in-ci-environment-skip-it-for-local-builds
- Discussion/guide: How to experiment with Bitrise configs locally, on your Mac/Linux: https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/how-to-experiment-with-bitrise-configs-locally-on-your-mac-linux/1751